# AirPort Express behaves strangely while being connected to ADSL modem

Tags: airport, network

I have an AirPort Express linked to an ADSL modem with Ethernet cable.

**Statement 1:** ADSL modem is set up as a router with DHCP, so any cable connection to it will provide an Internet access. If one just plug the cable from modem directly to laptop everything is fine, Internet works, no visible dropouts.

**Statement 2:** AirPort is set up as a bridge so it just transferes the connection of the modem. It has static IP, subnet mask, dns and router adresses set.

The issue is that AirPort blinks with green-none-yellow (1 second for a color change) and AirPort Utility is just keeping switching between *no status messages* and *1 status message*. When exists, status message is *WAN Ethernet is not connected*, though the cable was connected all the time. And during those two seconds of no-errors connection Internet via WiFi does work!

Assuming the Statement 1, I believe the problem lays somewhere inside the AirPort or its settings. I've googled this error but the only thing I found is that AirPort should be considered inoperable only in case of constant blinking of yellow-none which is definitely not my case, so my question is:

How can I get rid from this blinking and make my wifi connection persistent?

Comment: Do you have another wireless access point (linksys, dlink, etc.) that you can try to test that the Airport is the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, no